# c++ lambda delegates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++11, visual-studio-2012

EDIT: Well, at the suggestion of others, I created a minimal example... and it worked, so I will share it here for anyone in the future. Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
    char* str;
public:
    myClass()
    {
        str = "";
    }

    void funcA()
    {
        funcB([](myClass* mc)
            {
                mc->str = "HelloWorld";
            }
        );
    }

    void funcB(std::function<void (myClass*)> otherFunc)
    {
        otherFunc(this);
    }     

    void printStr()
    {
        cout << str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myClass mc;
    mc.funcA();
    mc.printStr();
    int done;
    cin >> done;
}
```

The reason my original code didn't work was because I had split the declaration and implementation of funcB into two parts (.h & .cpp), and in the .h I did this

```
void funcB(std::function<void (myClass*)> otherFunc = NULL)
```

as far as I can tell, you absolutely cannot pass in NULL here, which is annoying to me, and hopefully a bug. But other than that, it works.

Comment: Please post the compiler errors.

Comment: Your lambda isn't of the form `void (TravelManager*)` as required by your function prototype.  It's instead just `void ()`

Comment: To match the `std::function<>` argument, your lambda must take a `TravelManager*` by argument.

Comment: Additionally, it's likely that you don't have to capture `this` by reference, because based on your code structure you don't actually need reference to a local variable right?  What's the scope of the `set` function?  Is it a free function?  Or is it a member of the class?  Is this code the member of the same class or a different one?

Comment: Ok I still have errors with this updated code, the code is called in a bind method on the same class, but I can call it this way... it just still has errors, the most important of which is this: 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(431): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Comment: Post a minimal complete example, and the errors you get. See http://sscce.org/. Nobody here knows which line you're getting the error on, the definitions of any of the types that may or may not be relevant, etc.

Comment: If your minimal example doesn't exhibit the same problem as your real code, then it isn't really an example... ;-]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass `NULL` but you can pass `nullptr`.

Comment: +1 Indeed, either `std::function<void (myClass*)> otherFunc = std::function<void (myClass*)>()` or `std::function<void (myClass*)> otherFunc = nullptr` would be fine here, but clearly the latter is more succinct. On a more conformant compiler, I think `std::function<void (myClass*)> otherFunc = {}` should work too.